# View position changes after scrolling or reload table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

it is look good when first time load table view but problem is when scrolling tableview or reload tableview  then `lineView` position change.

```
func drowLine(_ cell: UITableViewCell)->UIView{
    let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0, width: cell.contentView.frame.size.width - 40 , height: 1))
    lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 56/255, green: 66/255, blue: 72/255, alpha: 0.149)
    return lineView
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: titleDisclosureIndicatorID, for: indexPath) as! TitleDisclosureIndicatorCell
       //......
        cell.contentView.addSubview(drowLine(cell))
    return cell
}


class TitleDisclosureIndicatorCell: BaseTableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
   //.....

}
```

**Initial load table view :**

[image]

**After scrolling and reload tableview line position change some of row :**

[image]

Comment: how does it change?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ image added

Answer (score 1):

Cells are being reused so I am guessing that you are keep adding the line multiple times.
You should approach this differently and use your subclass of `RegistrationFormCell`. Add the line to your storyboard file and you wont have the issue anymore.

Comment: as you scroll cell for row is being called again.

Comment: PoolHallJunkie is right, although I'm not sure this is the only issue (see the line rendered in date of birth and gender cells)

Comment: @MilanNosáľ  `date of birth and gender` table view get reload.on the other hand scrolling row line get more black

Comment: @PoolHallJunkie how can I fix this issue. would you share with.

Comment: @PoolHallJunkie I able to fixed color change issue but still get line change after reload or scrolling for `date of birth and gender`

Comment: If you create the uiview in the storyboard and use autolayout , you will not have this issue. And if you do , probably there is something else wrong. probably what happens here is that the content view is changing after the first load (common issue). try this :   `self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
        self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: @PoolHallJunkie unfortunately! we are doing everting programatically :) anyway  I will trying with your comment  tomorrow and get beck to you.